# Meaning of "subtle but pervasive message"

Tags: meaning

I was learning some essay techniques and noticed the expression:

> the subtle but pervasive message is that...

What does this exactly mean?

Comment: Questions of this kind are not accepted here, not unless you explain why you are still confused about the meaning after having looked the words up in a couple of good dictionaries. We're happy to help clarify, but this site is not a substitute for dictionaries.

Comment: I agree with @Tᴚoɯɐuo – This question would be much-improved if there were more [details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), such as what research you've done, what you learned, and [where you found the quote](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084), in case anyone wants more context.

Comment: I disagree—especially on *this* site where people are learning how to use English. Even knowing the meanings of the words themselves, I would still have a problem understanding the phrase as a whole. (If I weren't exposed to it.) The answer given does a great job of explaining it.

Comment: @JasonB - I'm not saying we can't cut a learner some slack. But, at the very least, an OP could say, "I looked up _pervasive_ in the dictionary, but the definition there (manifested throughout; pervading, permeating, penetrating or affecting everything) only confused me more." At least then everyone would know that an earnest attempt was made, and might have a better idea of where the confusion lies.

Answer (score 2):

It means the text convincing you of something you don't even know you are being convinced of.

Here is an example from a campaign I am involved with, trying to remove the constant messages sent to kids.

2 of these t-shirts are from the girls section and 2 from the boys section, can you tell which? of course you can, and the kids reading these t-shirts understand the message they are constantly being given from clothes, toys, television, adverts the whole of society.

[image: what is the message]

Comment: +1 This is a great answer.